# Should we burninate [rank]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The tag [rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rank) is just a bunch of questions which happen to involve the word "rank."  Many are SEO, but we also have sorting, various programmatic objects which happen to be called `rank()` or `RANK`, etc.  I don't see how anyone could be an expert in this.  It has 2 followers and hundreds of questions.  Burninate?

Comment: Only 455 questions to be edited.  Go for it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Apparently 456 now :) I agree this tag should be burninated before it gets out of control. It adds nothing of value to the question and has only been around for a few months.

Comment: Yeah I agree. Burninate it! I'll get to work as well.

Comment: We also have [tag:ranking], but that might be a candidate for synonymizing to [tag:sorting], so I'll leave it alone for now.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is 'burninate''?

Comment: @HoàngLong http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag

Comment: I think [tag:ranking] and [tag:sorting] are different. I doubt anyone looking for a ranking algorithm will be content with quicksort, nor will somebody looking for a sorting algorithm want to hear about [Elo](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) or [TrueSkill](http://research.microsoft.com/projects/trueskill/).